Creating a Windows Service to interact with a user context?
I have a Windows Service that runs an integration to QuickBooks Desktop.  It worked perfectly until QuickBooks 2024.  In QuickBooks 2024, their RequestProcessor (which I call) errors out in the QBSDKLOG file:
20241118.195130 E   8204    RequestProcessor    Could not find or create an instance of QuickBooks using InstanceFinder hr = 8004041c
If I run the exact same integration code as a desktop application rather than a service, it works perfectly.  This is clearly a bug in QuickBooks 2024, which I have filed with Intuit (case number 00162351, which is "With Engineering" for over a month), only to have it be completely ignored.  I am trying to find a work around for this.
How can I get a Windows Service or executable to run when the PC starts and is invisible to the user, and runs in a users context (which seems to be required for it to work in 2024)?  I have tried setting service to log in as a user and with local system checking interact with the desktop, but neither worked :(
Running it as an app, is causing all sorts of problems with users killing the app (out of ignorance) or logging off the PC and causing problems in the integration.  I am convinced that Intuit does not care to support me or this product, or fix this defect that they clearly introduced in Desktop 2024.
Any ideas on how to work around this Intuit defect?
